# "You are in emergency mode" / How do I fix this error?

Tags: boot, gnome, 17.04

System: Dell XPS 15 9560
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu Gnome 17.05

I've been using my Ubuntu install for about 2 weeks now with little to no issues. This morning I booted up and was greeted with this screen:

[Boot Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIRDS.jpg)

If I try to press enter or ctrl+D, it just prints the following, and doesn't allow me to type any commands:

[Boot Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UVH0.jpg)

I booted up with a live USB of Ubuntu and typed in "journalctl -xb" which gave me thousands of lines of output. I assume the ones highlighted in red were the problematic ones. They included:

- "ubuntu-gnome kernel: ACPI Error Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND
  ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 12 successful"
- "ubuntu-gnome networkmanager: ((devices/nm-device.c:970)): assertion '' failed"
- "ubuntu-gnome kernel: ath10k_pci: Could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin'"
- "ubuntu-gnome kernel: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e0
  device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
  Replay Timer Timeout

I've tried to include all the information I had so far. If I can upload anything else, I'm happy to do that.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do?